# Para que serve a interface Traversable no PHP?

Tags: php, interface, spliterator

No Manual do PHP podemos ver que algumas classes que podem ser iteradas com `foreach` implementam uma interface chamada `Traversable`.

Por exemplo, a classe [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Aí, quando eu tenho implementar num objeto meu a interface `Traversable`, um erro é gerado:

Exemplo:

```
 class Test implements Traversable{}
```

Gera:

> Class Test must implement interface Traversable as part of either Iterator or IteratorAggregate

Outra coisa interessante também: ela  é uma interface vazia.

Afinal, qual é a finalidade real de `Traversable` e por que não é possível implementá-la?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir explicar isso, vou ter que falar de três interfaces: Iterator, IteratorAggregate e a `Traversable`.

Vamos explicar por partes:

De acordo com o [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.traversable.php) (traduzido por mim, mais ou menos assim):

> Traversable: Interface para detectar se uma classe pode ser iterável com `foreach`.

Agora essa informação é importante.

> Interface **base abstrata** que não pode ser instanciada. Ao invés disso, você deve utilizar `IteratorAggregate` ou `Iterator`.

Você precisa entender um ponto: `Traversable` serve para detectar que uma classe é ou não iterável via `foreach`. Ela é uma interface especial, usanda internamente pelo PHP.

O PHP pede para você usar as interfaces `IteratorAggregate` ou `Iterator` porque essas duas interface estendem a interface `Traversable` (para quem não sabe, em php é possível uma interface herdar a outra).

E assim, o php usa `Traversable` para saber se a classe pode ser iterada com `foreach`, mas para definir o comportamento você deve usar `Iterator` ou `IteratorAggregate`.

## Mas porque duas interfaces, ao invés de uma?

Há mudança na forma da implementação. Com `Iterator` você precisa implementar 5 métodos em sua classe deverá ser iterada, ou seja, essa é a forma que definirá como a mesma se comportará no `foreach`.

Já no caso de `IteratorAggregate` você precisa apenas implementar um método, `getIterator`, que deverá retornar um outro objeto que implemente Iterator, para você poder iterar sobre itens de sua classe.

## Se já existe as duas outras interfaces, então pra que serve Traversable?

De maneira direta, podemos nos lembrar imediatamente que o PHP 5 aceita você definir o tipo de argumento que uma função ou método deverá receber. Isso se chama Indução de tipo.
Por exemplo, se quero que um argumento seja de uma determinada classe, eu devo definir isso no parâmetro da função/método.

Exemplo:

```
 function iter(MinhaClasse $objeto) {
 }
```

Porém, além de induzir a própria classe que será aceita na passagem do argumento, essa tipagem também permite que você possa passar uma classe que seja a classe pai, ou então a interface. Assim, além de o PHP checar se aquela classe é a passada, ele também pode checar se uma determinada classe implementa uma interface ou é filha de outra classe.

```
  class X {}
  class Y extends X{}
  class Z{}
  function eh_valido(X $x) {}

  eh_valido(new X); // SIM
  eh_valido(new Y); // SIM
  eh_valido(new Z); // Não
```

Sendo assim, se eu tenho uma classe que implementa `Iterator` e outra que implementa `IteratorAggregate`, como faria para aceitar as duas como parâmetro de uma função/método, já que as duas definem um comportamento da classe em relação a iteração? Sim, é só usar `Traversable` como indução de tipo.

Tomando como exemplo, a classe `ArrayIterator` no PHP implementa `Iterator`. Já a classe `ArrayObject` implementa `IteratorAggregate`. As duas são iteráveis com  `foreach`, pois as implementações das duas herdam `Traversable`.

Então, veja os seguintes testes:

```
 $obj = new ArrayObject;
 $it = new ArrayIterator($obj);


 var_dump($obj instanceof IteratorAggregate); // bool(true)
 var_dump($obj instanceof Iterator); // bool(false)
 var_dump($obj instanceof Traversable); // bool(true)


var_dump($it instanceof Iterator); // bool(true)
var_dump($it instanceof IteratorAggregate); // bool(false)
var_dump($it instanceof Traversable); // bool(true)
```

Logo, podemos fazer isso:

```
 function itera_isso_pra_mim(Traversable $iterator)
 {
       return get_class($iterator);
 }



itera_isso_pra_mim(new ArrayObject); // string(ArrayObject)
itera_isso_pra_mim(new ArrayIterator); // string(ArrayIterator)
itera_isso_pra_mim(new stdClass); // Gera um erro, pois não implementa nada que herde Traversable
```

Toda essa explicação que fiz é de suma importância para, quando você ver uma função da spl iterator, você entender o porquê de a definição do parâmetro ser `Traversable`.

Veja um exemplo com a função [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) (o manual em português está errado, você tem que olhar o original inglês).

Esqueleto da função:

```
iterator_to_array ( Traversable $iterator [, bool $use_keys = true ] )
```

Como exemplo, é possível usar como argumento de `iterator_to_array` as seguintes classes: `DatePeriod`, `ArrayIterator`, `ArrayObject`, `SplStack`, `CallbackFilterIterator` entre outros. Todas essas implementam, indiretamente, `Traversable`.

Comment: "Interface base abstrata ..."  frase bonita porém 'meio' redundante O.o, existe interface concreta? esse manual hein ...

Comment: Também concordo @rray. Muito estranho, mas é o que está no manual.