# Como verificar se um valor é iterável pelo foreach em PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, iterator

Em PHP, não apenas `arrays` são iteráveis, mas também alguns objetos específicos. Por exemplo, objetos que implementem a interface `Iterator` ou ainda `IteratorAggregate`. Outro exemplo é `stdClass` e `ArrayObject`, que iteram com `foreach`. Ainda assim, há o caso daquelas funções que usam `yield` internalmente. O `yield` faz com que a função possa retornar um valor que é iterável via `foreach`.

Sendo assim, qual é a forma segura de verificar se um valor é iterável com `foreach` via PHP, já que existem tantas variações?

Por exemplo, como poderia fazer as variáveis abaixo passar de acordo com um teste específico para checar se é iterável?

```
$a = new stdClass;
$b = new ArrayObject;
$c = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__);
$d = array(1, 2, 3);

$e = new PDO(); // não iterável
$f = 'Não iterável'; // não iterável
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Pra que serve a interface Traversable?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111675/para-que-serve-a-interface-traversable-no-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em PHP, todo `array` é iterável.

Qualquer objeto também podem ser usado no `foreach`, porém o comportamento não pode ser desejado, pois todas as propriedades públicas é que são usadas na iteração. Assim, você precisa definir a interface `Iterator` ou `IteratorAggregate` ou `RecursiveIterator` para determinar o comportamento da classe quando a instância da mesma é invocada no `foreach`.

Uma informação importante é que as interfaces `Iterator` ou `IteratorAggregate` herdam uma outra interface, chamada `Traversable`. Ela é usada para o PHP detectar internamente se a classe é iterável via `foreach`. Então quando você implementa `Iterator` ou `IteratorAggregate`, você implementa indiretamente `Traversable`. O `RecursiveIterator` por sua vez herda `Iterator`, portanto também indiretamente herda `Traversable`.

Resumindo: Toda interface de iteração em PHP herda `Traversable`. Então toda classe que implementa `Iterator`, é uma instância de `Traversable`.

As classes citadas no post, `ArrayObject` e `FileSystemIterator` possuem a implementações de `Iterator`. Então por isso são iteráveis.

Veja um teste no [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/uWDMJh)

O `yield` que foi citado na pergunta é usado para retornar uma instância da classe `Generator`. Ele também implementa `Iterator` e, portanto, implementa implicitamente `Traversable`.

Já o caso do `stdClass`, é o primeiro exemplo citado. Por ser um objeto vazio, todas as propriedades definidas nele são públicas. Então isso explica porque ele é iterável via `foreach`.

Com base nas informações obtidas acima, eu diria que a forma mais segura de verificar se um valor é iterável em PHP é :

```
is_array($valor) || $valor instanceof stdClass || $valor instanceof Traversable;
```

Você pode criar uma função para checar isso se quiser:

```
function is_iterable($value)
{
    return is_array($value) || $value instanceof stdClass || $value instanceof Traversable;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Nota: Esta resposta é apenas complementar

A partir da versão 7.1.0 do PHP existe a função [`is_iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php) é nativa, após testa-la nesta versão notei que objetos [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) não são considerados iteráveis, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->val = 1;
$foo->val2 = 2;

var_dump(is_iterable($foo));
```

Retornará `bool(false)`, então creio que um exemplo com "retrocompatibilidade" poderia ser algo como:

```
//Checa se já existe a função is_iterable
if (!function_exists('is_iterable'))
{
    //se não existir cria a função, por exemplo no PHP5.6 ou 7.0
    function is_iterable($value)
    {
        return is_array($value) || $value instanceof \Traversable;
    }
}
```

Outra maneira de "checar" no *PHP 7.1* seria usando a [**declaração de tipo `iterable`**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types), um código de exemplo seria:

```
function minhafuncao(iterable $valor)
{
    //Faça algo aqui
}

minhafuncao([1, 2, 3]); //Usando
```

Se passar `stdClass` por exemplo ou outro tipo que não seja iterável vai ocorrer uma [**`Exception TypeError`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) se fizer isto:

```
minhafuncao(new stdClass);
```

A Exception trará algo como:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to minhafuncao() must be
 iterable, object given, called in foo.php on line 7 and defined in foo.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 foo.php(7): minhafuncao(Object(stdClass))
#1 {main}
  thrown in foo.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to minhafuncao() mustbe iterable, object given, called in foo.php on line 7 and defined in foo.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 foo.php(7): minhafuncao(Object(stdClass))
#1 {main}
  thrown in foo.php on line 2
```

O que pode ser interessante se quiser criar uma função mais "restrita" (exigente)

Mais detalhes nesta pergunta [Para que serve o tipo iterable do PHP 7.1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197175/3635)

Comment: `is_iterable((array) new stdClass)` dá o quê, chefe?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `bool(true)` devido ao `cast`, mas creio que eles não consideram stdClass como iteravel porque ele só funciona em algumas situações, creio que com funções como `next();` e `current()` não funcione

Comment: Na verdade qualquer objeto castado para array é iterável. Um cast de object para array pega suas propriedades e transforma em um array associativo. https://3v4l.org/Ts0S8

Comment: @gmsantos vai além de "objetos": https://ideone.com/UlAh3b

Comment: Sim, array é iterable... qualquer coisa que seja convertido para array é iterable :) http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: @gmsantos acho que foi isso mesmo o que eu quis expor :) como disse no primeiro comentário pro Wallace, "devido ao cast"