# Para que serve o tipo iterable do PHP 7.1?

Tags: php, php-7.1

Estava vendo alguns códigos para testar o PHP 7.1 e encontrei o seguinte trecho:

```
function doLoop(iterable $iterable) {
    foreach ($iterable as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}

$data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
doLoop($data);
```

Com o `iterable` consigo garantir que o argumento passado seja um *array*, mas consigo chegar no mesmo resultado se fizer isso:

```
function doLoop(array $iterable) {
    foreach ($iterable as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}

$data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
doLoop($data);
```

Qual a diferença então de fato do `array` para o `iterable`? Ele realmente é um tipo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é um tipo, é um pseudo tipo (tal como o `callable`). A função dele é indicar que a função aceita como parâmetro tanto `array` como qualquer objeto que implementa a interface `Traversable`. Ou seja, aceita também objetos do tipo *array-like*, que funcionam em um *loop* `foreach`.

Se indicado no parâmetro de uma função, a mesma aceitará valores do tipo `array`, `Iterator`, `Generator`, etc. Se não for nenhum destes tipos, uma exceção do tipo `TypeError` é disparada.

```
function foo(iterable $iterable) {
    foreach ($iterable as $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Pode também ser utilizado para definir o retorno de uma função:

```
function bar(): iterable {
    return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Quando utilizado em parâmetros, o mesmo pode possuir valor padrão `null` ou mesmo um `array` vazio.

```
function foo(iterable $iterable = null) {
    // ...
}
```

E como o `generator` é um sub-tipo de `Traversable`, o seguinte é válido:

```
function gen(): iterable {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}
```

Basicamente, para saber se é um tipo possível de `iterable`, basta utilizar a função `is_iterable`:

```
var_dump(is_iterable([1, 2, 3])); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable(new ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3]))); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable((function () { yield 1; })())); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable(1)); // bool(false)
var_dump(is_iterable(new stdClass())); // bool(false)
```

A palavra `iterable` é definida como uma palavra reservada para nomes de classes, portanto classes, interfaces e traits não podem ser nomeadas como `iterable`.

> **Nota**: por mais que o PHP permita utilizar o `foreach` sobre objetos, iterando sobre as propriedades públicas do mesmo, o objeto não será considerado `iterable` se não for do tipo `Traversable`.

**Referência**: [PHP RFC: Iterable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable)